# Weka: how to convert the test data attibutes consistent with the train data attibutes?

Tags: weka, text-classification

I am doing the text classification task.

I build a classifier with train text data, has 1700+ attributes(words). However, my test data only has 500+ attributes(words), when i run test data on above model, it throws a **`Train and test set are not compatible`** exception. How could i convert the test data attributes consistent with train data's?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

Count lines in in each datafile, write down linecounts.

Copy both train and test file together into one file, apply the StringToWordVector Filter.

Temporarily delete the upper ~75% of that huge sparse matrix that results (the exact value could be 73.4542 % or something).

Export the remaining records corresponding to the lower 25%  of the transformed dataset (these rows represent your original test set)  into its own .arff file.

Now Undo the deletion operation of the upper 75%.  Invert the selection. Delete the lower 25% corresponding to your test set.

Run your classifier.

Apply the model on the test set, by loading in the new arff-file which you exported above.